# AFNetworking AFNetworkReachabilityCallback Error ( Ipad IOS6.3)

Tags: ios, afnetworking

My APP is working good in (ipad 6.1 Simulator,ipad 6.0 Simulator and ipad 5.1 Simulator).
But after installed in my ipad, it's not work any more.

I use the Organizer-Dervices to debug the error, and get the error messages:

```
Console:

Jul 31 21:55:27 Sandy ReportCrash[937] : Formulating crash report for process BenefitPad[781]
Jul 31 21:55:27 Sandy ReportCrash[937] : libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
```

```
Dervice Logs:

Incident Identifier: F6306353-BEF8-4626-8FA1-17F8C829AEE4
CrashReporter Key:   1a786173c1c72ae5d44172b3d641feee8e91a4af
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         BenefitPad [778]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D733430C-510D-4D2A-9D88-6361A6074485/BenefitPad.app/BenefitPad
Identifier:      BenefitPad
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-31 19:46:51.989 +0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x75417466
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3935c52c objc_retain + 12
1   BenefitPad                      0x001571fe 0xe8000 + 455166
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3140c034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424
3   Foundation                      0x31d22594 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
4   Foundation                      0x31d26056 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 26
5   BenefitPad                      0x0010cc12 0xe8000 + 150546
6   BenefitPad                      0x000fe2da 0xe8000 + 90842
7   BenefitPad                      0x00134cd8 0xe8000 + 314584
8   BenefitPad                      0x00135d02 0xe8000 + 318722
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3977711c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x397764b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3977b1b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 220
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3148ef36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
13  CoreFoundation                  0x31401eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
14  CoreFoundation                  0x31401d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  GraphicsServices                0x34fb62e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
16  UIKit                           0x333172fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
17  BenefitPad                      0x000fd92c 0xe8000 + 88364
18  BenefitPad                      0x000e9aec 0xe8000 + 6892

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3984d648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3977d974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3977d654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3984ceb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3984d048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31490040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3148ed9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31401eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31401d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x373f1500 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397b630e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397b61d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3985dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397abcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397aba12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397ab8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3985dd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397abcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397aba12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x397ab8a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

And the error is likely occurred in the method(File: AFHTTPClient.m  Line:309):

```
static void AFNetworkReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef __unused target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void *info) {
    AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = AFNetworkReachabilityStatusForFlags(flags);
    AFNetworkReachabilityStatusBlock block = (__bridge AFNetworkReachabilityStatusBlock)info;
    if (block) {
        block(status);
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter postNotificationName:AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:status] forKey:AFNetworkingReachabilityNotificationStatusItem]];
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's hard to tell because you haven't resymbolicated your logs, but you are probably running some code in response to a `AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification` posting.  This code is trying to access an object that has been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this.

The reason is as a property of 'NSDecimalNumber', after I change the propery from 'NSDecimalNumber' to 'NSString', it's work well.

This issue is nothing about 'AFNetworking'.